# Netbean autocomplete doesn't work in some folder

Tags: php, netbeans, yii

I have a `Yii 1.x` project, and i use `Netbeans 8.0.2.` In this website there is an admin folder in web folder. This is one netbeans project but 2 yii project with one framework (one for users, one for admins). When i am in the web folder the auto complete works, however it doesn't work in web/admin folder.

I tried everything:

-Delete cache manually - `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0.2`

-Reinstall Netbeans

-Delete the project without source code, after create a new project.

-Code completion on. (tools->option->editor->codecompletion)

-Updates

Here is my "about":

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 (Build 201411181905)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.0.2 Patch 2
Java: 1.8.0_11; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.11-b03
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_11-b12
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1250; hu_HU (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\Siki\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2
Cache directory: C:\Users\Siki\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0.2

So can i enable auto complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `Yii 1.x`, there is a certified `NetBeans plugin` for Yii 1.x in its plugin repository. This plugin will provide options like

- *Creating new Yii project from netbeans. No need to use Terminals*
- *Code completion.*
- *Go to a Class file by clicking on accessible snippets.*

Plug this in you NetBeans to get above benefits as well as to overcome auto code complication problem, which you mentioned in your post.

**Plugin page** @ http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/47246/php-yii-framework-netbeans-phpcc

Answer (score 1):

In `project properties > Include path`, add the folder where are the **yii framework base files**

Right click over the project in tab projects, then select properties

[Image project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTGcn.png)
This enables code completion.